# NHibernate: Mapping One-toOne Relationship having Composite IDs

Tags: .net, nhibernate, oracle10g

We have a situation wherein there is a Parent table and many Child tables. The Parent Table contains all transactions while the child tables are made to segregate specific type of transactions. The key structure is as follows:

> Parent Table - Contains all Transactions
>
> - Composite Primary Key
>
>   - TranId
>   - TranMonth
>
> Children Tables - Contains Transactions of specific type
>
> - Composite Primary Key (and also the Foreign Key from Parent table)
>
>   - TranId
>   - TranMonth

Request someone to help me out on how to map a one-to-one relationship between these tables in NHibernate.

Comment: That looks like table-per-subclass inheritance, not one-to-one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the composite id element in the mapping - see this [post](http://devlicio.us/blogs/anne_epstein/archive/2009/11/20/nhibernate-and-composite-keys.aspx) for an example